# A problem containing constrained motion of strings and a block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string, constrained-dynamics

Here is the question :-

[image]

Two methods came to my mind while trying to solve it, which are:

1. I assumed the velocity of M as *v*(upwards). Then, as the strings are inextensible the cosine component of *v* should be equal to *u*, if that doesn't happen then the strings will stretch or slack, which we don't want to happen.

Hence,
$$vcos\theta=u$$
Which gives us $v=u/cos\theta$ as our answer.

2. The point on M which is attached to both strings will have 2 velocities which will look like,

[image]

Its net velocity can be given by $2ucos\theta$ along the dotted normal. And as that point is on the block, the block will also move with the same velocity. This gives us $v=2ucos\theta$ as our answer.

The 1st method gives the correct answer but the 2nd method does not and I am looking for the reason behind it.

Comment: This question has been asked before here. I'm trying to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when it comes to constraint relation of inextensible strings the components of  velocity ,acceleration etc,of a particle attached to it are taken along the direction of the string as its length cannot change.It is wrong to take the component of the veleocity of the string in the direction of motion of the object.Furthermore, your equation would imply that at $\theta$=0 the particle is moving with 2v but the string is moving at v, meaning the string is not taut which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your first equation is not particularly obvious to me, but if you take the distances from where the cord leaves the pulley to where it connects to the mass: vertical, y, horizontal, x, and length, L, then: y = L cos(θ) and x = L sin(θ).  Take the derivative of each equation with respect to, t, and eliminate the dθ/dt, then you get dy/dt = (dL/dt)/cos(θ).